# The NavigationBar is not totally hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want to hide the NavigationBar and the stateBar to show fullScreen Image, but it seems that the navigationBar is not totally hidden:

[image]

The code is as below:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

The height of the part which is not hidden is the same as the stateBar. How to fix this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your Info.plist;

Status bar is initially hidden YES

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

or:

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

?